# The use of "among"

Tags: grammar, among-between

**Among the places I visited were West Point, Tarrytown, the home of Washington Irving, where I walked through "Sleepy Hollow."**

**Among Mrs. Marsh's attributes was mind reading.**

Could someone please explain to me the meaning and the grammatical structure of these sentences above using "among" in the front? That only way of using “among" I know is, for example, say "he is the only boy among all the students.

If possible, could you list any other words rather than "among" that can be used with the similar sentence structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Some of" would be equivalent (or better) in the first example. "One of" would work in the second.
Also, in the first example you should use "and" somewhere in the list - before "Tarrytown" if Tarrytown *is* the home of Washington Irving or after "Tarrytown" if it isn't.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This question has bothered me for a while. I wonder whether "among" is more formal in writing than "Some of/ one of"?

Comment: Or is it that Westpoint, Tarrytown (in the "city, province" form) is one place that is the home of Washington Irving and where they walked through "Sleepy Hollow"?